# Create a recyclable function and converting a string to a variable name

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I'm trying to make a check box to show/hide a HTML element, but I am trying to make it as efficient as possible (recycling one function and enabling it to evolve, rather than manually and statically writing unique functions).

I have already succeeded at this once, but in a slightly different scenario (included: "JavaScript Extract - Working Recycled Function") but cannot get it to work in this new scenario (included: "JavaScript Extract - Not Working Recycled Function). I have scavenged what I can from it but I am having difficultly this time around. My brain has kinda ground to a halt after a couple of hours to solving other problems. I have multiple elements waiting to also use this, but for now I'm just trying to get it to work with the Google element first.

**HTML Extract**

```
<div id="googleContainer">
    <input type="text" id="googleSearchBox" title="Google Search" class="searchBox" />
    <input type="button" id="googleSearchButton" onClick="execSearchWithClick(this.id)" />
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="googleCheck" checked="checked" onClick="setPref(this.id)"/>
```

**JavaScript Extract - Working Recycled Function**

```
var googleHome = "http://www.google.com/"; //Set home page
var googleSearchURL = googleHome + "search?q="; //Prime search URL
function execSearchWithClick(id){
    alert(id) //Check ID
    var searchBox = document.getElementById(id.replace("Button", "Box")); //Convert "googleSearchButton" to "googleSearchBox" to match target element
    var searchQuery = searchBox.value; //Extract value from converted string-to-variable

    if (searchQuery == ""){
        if (id == "googleSearchButton") {
            window.open(googleHome);
        } //I would use "if(condition && condition)" rather than nested IFs here, but I plan to use ELSE IF very soon
    } else {
        if (id == "googleSearchButton") {
            window.open(googleSearchURL + searchQuery);
        } 
    }
}
```

**JavaScript Extract - Not Working Recycled Function**

```
var googleDisplay = true;
function setPref(id){
    alert(id) //Check ID
    var checkboxDisplayString = document.getElementById(id.replace("Check", "Display")); //Convert "googleCheck" to "googleDisplay" to match boolean variable
    alert(checkboxDisplayString) //Null value reply
    var checkboxDisplayVar = checkboxDisplayString //Convert (what I suspect to be) String to variable name
    alert(checkboxDisplayVar) //Null value reply

    if (id == "googleCheck" && checkboxDisplayVar == true){
        checkboxDisplayVar = false;
        applyPref();
    } else {
        checkboxDisplayVar = true;
        applyPref();
    }
}

function applyPref(){
    if (googleDisplay == true){
        document.getElementById("googleContainer").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("googleContainer").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've added much more detail for those who asked now. Sorry if everything has become more confusing.

Comment: Is there reason not to use a library? (e.g. jQuery)

Comment: Where is this "googleDisplay" HTML element?  If there's no such element, then the null result from "getElementById()" isn't surprising.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, sorry. Could you be very explicit about exactly what you want the code to do? Thanks

Comment: I haven't included it in the extract because it points to other files and I'd then have to include those and it'll just get messy here. Suffice to say, I have already succeeded in hiding this element (so I know that it works and can be done) but it wasn't very cleanly written and I decided to retry it.

Comment: And I really don't like using jQuery. I'm only starting to learn JavaScript and I prefer to learn it from the ground up, not taking the easy way out.

Comment: I've added the googleDisplay element now. Just ignore the JavaScript functions it's pointing to. They work.

Comment: That's clearer. To be honest, I don't tend to like solutions that involve too much knowledge of 'special' IDs (although this can be made to work). It may be better to group the checkbox and other elements in the DOM so that you can exploit their relationship in the DOM instead. I take your point about jQuery as well, but it's *really* helpful for exactly the kind of stuff that you're doing.

Comment: I may have considered alternatives if I hadn't already got this working in another scenario (now included). Does the extra information now provide more useful insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my attempt:

```
    function setPref(id){
        var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
        applyPref(checkbox.checked);      
    }

    function applyPref(show){
        if (show){
            document.getElementById("googleContainer").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("googleContainer").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

I may be missing something, but I think that something like the above should work

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. It kind of worked. I had to modify it to:

function setPref(id){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
    applyPref(checkbox.checked, id);      
}

function applyPref(show, id){
 var container = document.getElementById(id.replace("Check", "Container"));
 
    if (show){
        container.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        container.style.display = "none";
    }
}

so that it would work with whatever checkbox was ticked. But yeah, thanks dude!

Comment: Glad it helped. I think in your 'non-working' version there was some confusion between the name of a JavaScript variable and the ids of the elements on the page, but anyway, it looks like you're there now. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.. instead of converting variable names, just pass the variables to your function onCLick.

```
<div id="one" style="width:100%;height:100px;background-color:#000;"></div>
<form>
<input id="one-check" type="checkbox" name="one" onclick="showOrHide('one');">
</form>
<div id="two" style="width:100%;height:100px;background-color:#000;"></div>
<form>
<input id="two-check" type="checkbox" name="two" onclick="showOrHide('two');">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function showOrHide(id){

alert(id);

var checkBox = document.getElementById(id+'-check');

if (checkBox.checked == 1){

document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";

} else {

document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";

}

}
```

Comment: Rather than edit my entire code, I put it into here: http://jsfiddle.net/LyTmb/1/

It didn't seem to do much.. Plus I prefer to have code that I understand. I don't really get what's going on there. :L

Comment: Sorry, i didn't relise you were using checkboxes, have updated it. >> http://jsfiddle.net/5ZtfG/

Comment: Whilst I do very much appreciate your time and effort, kind sir, my problem has been solved. But your way was good too! :)

I hope you take to jsfiddle, also. It's quite a useful tool! :D